# Visual studio c++ documentation generator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, documentation

Is there a way to get documentation(like javadoc) in a visual-c++ project?

I'm using visual studio 2010.

thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use the **XML-Documentation** format, supported by VS2010, too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177226%28VS.80%29.aspx

After commenting your code, you can use **Sandcastle** to create a MSDN-like documentation: http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/. (Here is a GUI representation for Sandcastle, which is a lot easier to use: https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB)

I use **AtomineerUtils** to create the XML-Documentation headers automatically. This tool will help you a lot. You can have free base version here: http://www.atomineerutils.com/products.php

Comment: +1 -- not only does this produce great looking docs, the compiler will annotate the output with the types and such the comments are attached to and all kinds of other goodies. If you need to fail over to something cross platform, Doxygen can recognize this format as well.

Comment: I am having trouble figuring this out for a C++ project, I've found this: Provide support for unmanaged C++ ( http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/workitem/3855 ) and Sample using C/C++ project? ( http://shfb.codeplex.com/discussions/217100/ ). So is it really possible to use Sandcastle for native C++?

Comment: [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) and [CppTripleSlash](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/22333333-fd6f-4dcb-8223-52701eddd7ad) are other alternatives to create the xml doc headers automatically

Answer (score 14):

You can have a look at [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

Comment: I have to say I'm not impressed by Doxygen. Even now (2017) there appears to be no way to generate parameter documentation that automatically includes the parameter type, which you'd have thought would be a pretty fundamental requirement.

Comment: That's for C++ btw.

Answer (score 3):

You could use my addin, [Atomineer Pro Documentation](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) to quickly generate documentation comments in Documentation-XML, Doxygen, Qt or JavaDoc format. Then use Sandcastle (DocXml) or Doxygen (DocXml, Doxygen, Qt, Javadoc) to convert this documentation into external documentation files.

I'd recommend uing DocXml format because all the above tools work with it, and Visual Studio recognises it (it syntax colours it, and it builds the docs into its intellisense database so it appears in tool-tip help as you type class/method names into your code).

Answer (score 3):

Also, take a look at [CppTripleSlash - xml doc comments for c++](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/22333333-fd6f-4dcb-8223-52701eddd7ad). It is a free Visual Studio 2015, 2013, 2012, 2010 extension.

Answer (score 1):

One way to generate documentation is - you guessed it - **javadoc**. You simply have to comment the same way you usually do, and javadoc does a good job of converting them to HTML/LaTeX style.

Of course, that's not the only solution. I'll leave room for others.

Comment: Um.. Java and C++ are similar, but they are not that similar. Javadoc is not going to know what to do when it encounters things like templates and such in the source code.

Comment: @Billy: You can use Javadoc style comments with Doxygen, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2015 then there is a Doxygen generator written for the Macro explorer extension which uses JavaScript for it's macro language.

Project is on github here: https://github.com/cppocl/visual_studio_macros

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind, some hand written documentation, then sphinx is the perfect tool.

http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/

and here is example:

http://ceres-solver.org/

```
sphinx-build -b singlehtml doc/ build/
```